# Why does / return an empty tuple in an IPython console

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

When I type a slash into an IPython console, it returns an empty tuple:

```
In[1]: /
Out[1]: ()
```

Why is this? I am on a mac. I am using Jupyter QtConsole with Python 3.5.2.

Comment: The python-internals tag isn't applicable for this specific question so I'll be removing it. This could be considered an implementation detail of IPython.

Comment: Ok, that's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From typing `?` and reading it in IPython:

> You can force auto-parentheses by using '/' as the first character
>   of a line.  For example::
>
> ```
> In [1]: /globals             # becomes 'globals()'
> ```
>
> Note that the '/' MUST be the first character on the line!  This
>   won't work::
>
> ```
> In [2]: print /globals    # syntax error
> ```

So `/` all by itself just adds parentheses to the word after it.  If no word, you just get `()`.

Answer (score 1):

> [You can force automatic parentheses by using ‘/’ as the first character of a line.](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes)

Using a forward slash adds parentheses:

```
/print 1 2 3
```

is equivalent to:

```
print(1, 2, 3)
```